# Does training legs affect recovery of upper body muscles given adequate carbohydrate and protein intake?

Tags: exercise, exercise-frequency

Simple question:

I have the following exercise regime (each line is another day):
Upper Body
Legs
Back
Legs
Upper Body
Legs
Back

I do 2-3 different exercise per day with 2-3 sets each.

My legs are very muscular, my upper body and back could be improved. Would I improve faster If I skipped legs for a period of time until my upper body / back strength increased so my body could focus on muscle growth in these areas or does it not matter, given that I pay attention to adequate protein and carbohydrate intake?

Comment: Maybe this question could be better answered on Biology stack exchange?

Comment: Probably not. Even though you are hitting the gym 7 days per week, 2-3 sets for 2-3 exercises is not a whole lot of volume. If you were working out more, it might be an issue of recovery, but as long as you are able to put your all into all the workouts and feel rested each day, then you shouldn't be inhibiting muscle growth from your leg workouts.